# Using Syslog for user defined program

Tags: c, linux, syslog

I am trying to use syslog for the logging within my application.

SO, i defnied my own tag like

!myprog
*.* /var/log/myprog.log
!*

and in the C code, I have used openlog and syslog() function with local0 and appropriate levels.

Now, my issue is that in the file myprog.log, i am getting kernel; and other messages also along with my messages and I only want my messages in there.

I have tried many options but nothing working out.

So, is there any way where i can do this? Can anybody give some hint?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "many options" that you tried, and why they "don't work"?

Comment: http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/glibc/html_chapter/libc_18.html this might help